# Bootstrap 3: switching navbar with 2 rows on desktop to navbar with one row on mobile

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar, responsive

i try to achive collapsing a two-row-navigation on desktop to a one-row header on mobile. the first row is the top-bar, the second row the main-navigation. how can i hide the second bar on mobile devices to achive the following:

Thanks in advance for a little help!

Desktop

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|   BRAND                                               Call us | Cart | Login  | 
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|                              Link 1  |  Link 2 |  Link 3 |  Link 4 |  Link 5  |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Mobile

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| TOGGLE_MAIN                           BRAND                        TOGGLE_TOP | 
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**Here is what i currently have:**

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/bmuma5ow/)

Comment: What do you want to achive that is not in your fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to hide the second row in mobile view add "hidden-xs" after navbar navbar-default in your second row div like this:

```
<!-- Second Row -->
<div class="navbar navbar-default hidden-xs" id="header">

<div class="container">
<div class="row">  
<div class="navbar-header"> [...]
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bmuma5ow/13/

EDIT //--------------

Here is the working solution (removed "hidden-xs" and edited the CSS):

```
@media (max-width : 767px) {
  .navbar-brand {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin:0 auto;
    z-index:-1;
  }
  .header #toggleTop {
    float:left;
    margin-left:15px;
  }
  .navbar-default {
      background-color: #fff;
      border-width: 0;
      margin-top: 0px;
      z-index: 5;
  }
  #navbar-collapse2 {
   margin-top: 50px;
  }
}
```

Look Here: http://jsfiddle.net/bmuma5ow/15/

Comment: ok, the second row is hidden, but with "hidden-xs" the collapsed menu does not trigger on click

Comment: Theres an other solution. Sorry for possible syntaxerrors... Done this with my smartphone ^^

Comment: nice ;) it would be great if you mark my answer as the right answer

Comment: can you please update the link in your anwer with the link in the comment. thanks.

Comment: done :), and cleaned up the css, too. forgot a "}" on my Smartphone :D